# Custom view won't add subview

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have a view controller that's inheriting a view from it's preceding view, like a floating, draggable view controller with a video mini player (like the YouTube app). When I show the second vc, I'm actually hiding its own view before adding all of its subviews to a new, custom view so it seems like the first view controller is still present.

This new, custom view is adding my `UIButton`, but not my two custom `UIViews`. One of these custom views contains a tableview, which is nowhere to be found. I'm concerned this may be a constraint problem, where I need to add constraints to the new view programmatically or something like that. Any ideas?

`onView` = first controller's view

```
    class DetailViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    var initialFirstViewFrame: CGRect!
        var onView: UIView!
        var isExpandedMode: Bool!
        var player: UIWebView!
        var youtubeFrame: CGRect!
        var tblFrame: CGRect!
        var restrictOffset: CGFloat!
        var restrictTrueOffset: CGFloat!
        var restictYaxis: CGFloat!
        var transparentView: UIView!

        @IBOutlet weak var viewTable: UIView!
        @IBOutlet weak var tblView: UITableView!
        @IBOutlet weak var viewYouTube: UIView!
        @IBOutlet weak var btnDown: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {


            var dispatchTime: dispatch_time_t = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(0.8 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
            dispatch_after(dispatchTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

                self.calculateFrames()


            })

            var pan: UIPanGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "panAction")
            pan.delegate = self
            self.viewYouTube.addGestureRecognizer(pan)
            isExpandedMode = true
            self.btnDown.hidden = true

        }
    func calculateFrames() {

            youtubeFrame = self.viewYouTube.frame
            tblFrame = self.viewTable.frame

            UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarHidden(true, withAnimation: UIStatusBarAnimation.Slide)

            self.viewYouTube.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints() == true
            self.viewTable.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints() == true

            self.viewYouTube.frame = youtubeFrame
            self.viewTable.frame = tblFrame

            self.player.backgroundColor = UIColor.purpleColor()
            self.viewYouTube.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()

            restrictOffset=self.initialFirstViewFrame.size.width-200;
            restrictTrueOffset = self.initialFirstViewFrame.size.height - 180;
            restictYaxis=self.initialFirstViewFrame.size.height-self.viewYouTube.frame.size.height

            self.view.hidden = true
            transparentView = UIView(frame: self.initialFirstViewFrame)
            transparentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
            transparentView.alpha = 0.9

            self.onView.addSubview(transparentView)

/////// self.viewTable and self.viewYouTube don't load. They have AutoLayout constraints in storyboard and I'm trying to add their views to a different UIView/////////////
            self.onView.addSubview(self.viewTable)
            self.onView.addSubview(self.viewYouTube)
            self.onView.addSubview(self.btnDown)
        }
```